# How to cleanly reinstall all workspaces with yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a yarn workspace with a lot of projects. Something is messed up and I'd like to force delete all node_modules and reinstall all cleanly instead of me manually going into each project and manually deleting node_modules

I couldnt find anything on https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/ and https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install or other pages on how to do something like that

```
1.22.4
```